# I have the URL www.something.com/HereWeGo, I want to get HereWeGo without the 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Consider the URL www.something.com/HereWeGo.  When someone enters the url, the site shows a 404 error since the directory does not exists.  I can parse the URL to get the query and HereWeGo, but cannot stop it from going to a 404 error.

How can I achieve it by PHP, if it is possible to avoid .htaccess now

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to rewrite your URLs so `/something` directs to `index.php?q=/something`, the thing is your web server usually throws a 404 by default if the file / directory cannot be found and there are no `RewriteRules` associated with it, even if you can parse the URL from the error page and find the information you need.

Is there a valid reason why you can't use `.htaccess`? I would strongly suggest you use it if you can. Not least because at the moment a 404 will mean Google will not index your page.

[This article](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Services/Make-Dynamic-URLs-Search-Engine-Friendly/2/) will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You just can't avoid "touching" .htaccess, at least for rewriting all requests to single file ( or defining default 404 file ). You are using Apache, not PHP for the server, right?

Take Kohana 3 Framework for example ( and most other frameworks ), all requests are rewritten to index.php file, which then handles the routes for the request.

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Code below will handle everything that responds with a 404 and redirect it.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /somefile.php
```

In the somefile.php you can then check if referer is 'local' ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) and which query string it was about, responding with whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use mod_rewrite for that specific folder, or you could use your own custom 404 page (read [this article](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Apache/Custom-Error-404-Documents-with-PHP/)).

Answer (score 1):

this is something that you need to configure on the webserver, in a `.htaccess` file. Take a look at the syntax for the `redirect` or `rewrite`. It isn't possible to do this in PHP alone as it is the webserver which processes the URL request.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, setting up custom 404 (and other web server errors) are part of your webserver environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid a .htaccess redirect unless you change your apache (or other webservers) configuration to redirect your 404 errors to your own *.php file instead of the default error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a php file, such as `404.php` as your 404 error handler file.  After doing this have code in `404.php` that looks something like this:

```
if (stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST URI"],"HereWeGo")
{
//add handling code here
}
```

Comment: assuming any radom for HereWeGo

Answer (score 0):

On your destination page simply call--

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
```

--to override the default 404 status code.